# Software RAID on SBS/Server 08

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, software-raid

We recently had problems with our SBS 08 server, and we disabled the software raid 1 of our C:

Now that everything is back to normal, I wanted to re-enable it in the disk management, right-click on C: -> Add mirror, but it's greyed, same thing for the old other volume we used for the raid.

We broke something but i don't know what, can you help us plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you broke the mirror instead of removing it (creating two volumes, one from each half of the mirror). Assuming that's the case, delete the volume that you're not using that was created during that "Break Mirror" operation to free the space. Then you'll be able to add a mirror to the "C:" volume.

Comment: Thx for you answer, so to be clear, I have my C: and the other volume we used for the raid (I:). So I have to delete I:, then format it and "add a mirror" on C:. It will then resync the I: with the C: ? What i'm afraid of is that it will resync the C: based on what is on the I: !

Comment: Delete the I: volume so that the disk has free space. Do not create or format a new volume-- just right-click the C: volume and the "Add Mirror" option will be available. If you create and format a volume you will not be able to add a mirror.